# How to add or sum multiple variables and return an int

Tags: python, class, methods

I seem to have a problem with converting types properly in general.  This is just my most recent example.  I want to take the variables b, w, r, u, g, and colorless, add their values together, and return an int.  I'm posting the entire created class because its entirely likely that I have more than one problem here.

```
import re

class MTG_card:

    def __init__(self, card_type, rarity, mana_cost, modifier_1=None, modifier_2=None, modifier_3=None):

        self.card_type = card_type
        self.rarity = rarity
        self.mana_cost = mana_cost
        self.modifier_1 = modifier_1
        self.modifier_2 = modifier_2
        self.modifier_3 = modifier_3

    def conv_mana_cost(self):

        for cost in self.mana_cost:
            b = self.mana_cost.count('b')
            w = self.mana_cost.count('w')
            r = self.mana_cost.count('r')
            u = self.mana_cost.count('u')
            g = self.mana_cost.count('g')
            colorless = [int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', self.mana_cost)]

        return (b + w + r + u + g + colorless)

obj_1 = MTG_card('enchantment', 'rare', 'b, b, g, 3')
print(obj_1.conv_mana_cost())
```

I was expecting to get a return of 6 but instead I got...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/6h/f_vphymd1dj11mtbg20qwxsm0000gn/T/ipykernel_21902/1882525478.py in <module>
     25 
     26 obj_1 = MTG_card('enchantment', 'rare', 'b, b, g, 3')
---> 27 print(obj_1.conv_mana_cost())

/var/folders/6h/f_vphymd1dj11mtbg20qwxsm0000gn/T/ipykernel_21902/1882525478.py in conv_mana_cost(self)
     22             colorless = [int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', self.mana_cost)]
     23 
---> 24         return (b + w + r + u + g + colorless)
     25 
     26 obj_1 = MTG_card('enchantment', 'rare', 'b, b, g, 3')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: There are several problems here.  You have a loop with `cost` as the variable, but the code in your loop does not use `cost`.  `colorless` is, in fact, a list, and you can't add an integer and a list.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Do you mean to add `sum(colorless)` instead?

Comment: I want to be able to enter a string 'b, b, g, 3' for the `mana_cost` parameter in my `MTG_card` class and then have the method `conv_mana_cost` count the number of b, w, r, u, g and colorless (represented by the '3') and return a single integer.

Comment: for `colorless` I grabbed some code off another stackoverflow.  I want to be able to parse the integer out of the string.  It might not be necessary.  Some parameter input and return examples for `mana_cost` and then `conv_mana_cost` would be `'b, b, 2'` = 4 , `'u, u, g, w, 1'` = 5 , `'g, b, w, r, r, 4'` = 8.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I am obviously very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own problem.  I was making this more complicated than I needed to.  Instead of trying to count each occurence of `b, w, r, u, g` I should have just used the `len()` function.

```
class MTG_card:

def __init__(self, card_type, rarity, mana_cost, modifier_1=None, modifier_2=None, modifier_3=None):

    self.card_type = card_type
    self.rarity = rarity
    self.mana_cost = mana_cost
    self.modifier_1 = modifier_1
    self.modifier_2 = modifier_2
    self.modifier_3 = modifier_3

def colorless(self):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in self.mana_cost)

def conv_mana_cost(self):
    colorless = int(self.mana_cost[-1])
    mana_list = [i for i in self.mana_cost]

    if MTG_card.colorless(self) == True:
        x = len(mana_list) - 1 + colorless

    elif MTG_card.colorless(self) == False:
        colorless == 0
        x = len(mana_list)

    return x

obj_1 = MTG_card('enchantment', 'rare', 'bbgu3')
MTG_card.conv_mana_cost(obj_1)
```

This returns 7 as expected.